# Having @RequestBody and HttpServletRequest in the same Controller method

Tags: spring, rest

I have a situation where i have to update the request before i process it. basically, I will have to update the request with a property which can change with time. It is not practical to ask the consumer send the property along with request.. So, I feel like the only way to do it is.. update the request in controller method before processing it..

```
@RequestMapping(value="/**", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void processRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest, HttpServletResponse response )
```

Untill now, HttpServletRequest is used in the controller method. the request is then read as stream and then converted to json string to get processed. I am thinking to replace it with @RequestBody and have the request read into a pojo, then update, then process. But, I also need the pathInfo from HttpServletRequest to identify which uri i need to process the request for..

So, Can i use both @RequestBody and HttpServletRequest in the same method??
I tried it and i dint see any issues.. But, I wanted to check if there is any thing i am missing..

```
@RequestMapping(value="/**", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void processRequest(@RequestBody final DateRequest request, HttpServletRequest servletRequest, HttpServletResponse response )
```

Please advise..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fine and supported by Spring. As a matter of fact, I just finished writing a controller method virtually identical to the one you use in your example. Spring is very flexible with what is allowed for a method decorated with `@RequestMapping`. According to [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-methods):

> `@RequestMapping` handler methods have a flexible signature and can choose from a range of supported controller method arguments and return values. ... The table below shows supported controller method arguments.
>
> [ See documentation for complete table ]

In the table of acceptable argument types, it specifically allows `HttpServletRequest`, `HttpServletResponse`, and objects annotated with `@RequestBody`.

So you should be set, according to your findings, the fact that other people are doing this, and the documentation specifically mentioning it.